# git stash drop oldest stashes ( say oldest 5 stashes)

Tags: git, git-stash

How do I drop oldest stashes (say oldest 5 stashes) in one statement instead of doing something like this:

```
git stash drop stash@{3}
git stash drop stash@{4}
git stash drop stash@{5}
git stash drop stash@{6}
git stash drop stash@{7}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to an anonymous user's edit, the correct command would look like this:

```
git stash list | cut -f 1 -d : | tail -5 | sort -r | xargs -n 1 git stash drop
```

Here's his/her explanations:

- `git stash list`: List all your stashes
- `cut -f 1 -d`: Select only the first column (stash identifier, for example stash@{29})
- `tail -5`: Keep only the last five lines
- `sort -r`: Invert the order of the lines to drop the oldest stash first (otherwise remaining stashes get new names after each removal)
- `xargs -n 1 git stash drop`: For each line transmitted in the pipe, execute git stash drop, since `git stash drop` [may] support only one stash a time.

All kudos to the mysterious stranger.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  One suggestion: maybe use `tac` instead of `sort -r` to reverse the lines to handle if there are more than 9 stashes.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is great. And if you may use it often, you can add it to a shell function like this which would take an argument for number of old stashes you want to remove:

```
git-stash-prune() {
    git stash list | cut -f 1 -d : | tail -"$1" | sort -r | xargs -n 1 git stash drop 
}
```

Then you can call it like this for example would delete the last 10 stashes.

```
git-stash-prune 10
```

Comment: this helped me a great deal!!! thank you @lacostenycoder!! I had over 200 stashes because I like to experiment but some were too old to keep after a year or so...

Comment: @SoftDev30_15 Glad you found this helpful. I have a bunch more of [useful terminal functions I use a lot here](https://gist.github.com/lacostenycoder/9f56bebf4d15f6add19a068d23101c49) and if you find any of them useful [please let me know here](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/lacostenycoder)