# git stash drop: How can I delete older stashed states without dropping the latest X?

Tags: git, version-control, git-stash

What I already have discoverd:

```
git stash list
```

... for listing all my stashes.

```
git stash show -p stash@{0} --name-only
```

To list all files within that stash (here the latest stash at position 0).

Now I have a project with hundreds of old stashed changes which will not be needed anymore. I know I could delete them all:

```
git stash clear
```

... or delete single stashes like this (deletes the stash with 87 stashes afterwards):

```
git stash drop stash@{87}
```

However I would like to delete the stashes 3-107. With a risky guess I tried:

```
git stash drop stash@{3-107} -- does not work
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git stash drop oldest stashes ( say oldest 5 stashes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34345691/git-stash-drop-oldest-stashes-say-oldest-5-stashes)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-stash%5D+delete+old+stashes

Comment: @phd Very similar but not really a duplicated as I asked how to drop all but the latest X instead of how to drop the latest X. Should not mark it as duplicate as the answers are less cryptical here, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: We have to loop backwards because removing a stash changes the index of all stashes.

`git stash drop` doesn't accept more than one revision at a time;

```
$ git stash drop stash@\{{4..1}\}
Too many revisions specified: 'stash@{4}' 'stash@{3}' 'stash@{2}' 'stash@{1}'
```

You could achieve this with a loop in your shell. For example in `bash`;

```
$ for i in {4..1}; do
>     git stash drop stash@{$i};
> done
Dropped stash@{4} (175f810a53b06da05752b5f08d0b6550ca10dc55)
Dropped stash@{3} (3526a0929dac4e9042f7abd806846b5d527b0f2a)
Dropped stash@{2} (44357bb60f406d29a5d39ea0b5586578223953ac)
Dropped stash@{1} (c97f46ecab45846cc2c6138d7ca05348293344ce)
```

Comment: Dangerous, dangerous!!! When you drop stash@{1} it looks fine but now the other stashes have adjusted the numbering.

Comment: Interesting! I'll do some testing and provide a safe solution. I expect looping backwards is safe then?

Comment: I added my own recipe, just in case.

Comment: @eftshift0 Fixed!

Comment: I did `for i in {107..3}
do
   git stash drop stash@{$i};
done`
and it worked well for me. I think both solutions are equally good now?

Comment: Missing a **;** after the closing **}**

Comment: Note that you can also just drop `stash@{1}` four times. Personally, I find this the easiest, but I'm odd. :-) (More seriously, I just try to avoid the situation by rarely using `git stash` at all.)

Answer (score 4):

You might try this:

```
i=3; while [ $i -lt 104 ]; do git stash pop stash@{3}; i=$(( $i + 1 )); done
```

Always drop 3 because when you drop 3 what was 4 is now 3 and so on so you keep on dropping stash@{3}. Either way **use with EXTREME care!**

Comment: Sorry if this question is noobish but does this loop work in all operating systems' bashes or what kind of bash language is it?

Comment: works on bash.... don't know about other interpreters like ksh or dash or whatever.

Comment: @[Blackbam](https://stackoverflow.com/u/576746): this solution doesn’t work in *any* shell on any operating system because there’s a `then` in a `for` loop. Replace it with `do`.

Comment: Good catch! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Example Stash List:

You can use `git stash list` command to see your stash list.

```
stash@{0}: On main: cell click away deselet bug fix
stash@{1}: On main: stop propagation added
stash@{2}: On main: Split layout new plan button cover from drawing fixed
stash@{3}: On main: free trial changes
stash@{4}: On main: auto start free trial
stash@{5}: On main: fixed stage size with zoom
stash@{6}: On main: stage resize
stash@{7}: On main: resize half done
stash@{8}: On main: resize events removed
stash@{9}: On new-navigation-menu: project changes
stash@{10}: On main: fixed height drawing stage
stash@{11}: On main: plan image size change fail
stash@{12}: On main: plan configure model changes done
stash@{13}: On main: after merge plan sheet model
stash@{14}: On main: enter key scale model bug fixed
```

Stashes need to keep : **From 0 to 10**

Stashes need to remove : **From 11 to 14**

**(Using Windows Terminal)**

```
git stash drop stash@{11}
```

I repeat this command 4 times. (You will be able to use a while loop as well)

> 1st Time : stash@{11} romoved.
>
> 2nd Time : stash@{12} romoved.
>
> 3rd Time : stash@{13} romoved.
>
> 4th Time : stash@{14} romoved.

**Update:**

Using for loop (Windows Command Prompt)

```
for /L %n in (14,-1,11) do git stash drop stash@{%n}
```

Done :)

Comment: In combination with a bash loop I guess you can drop them all together.

Answer (score 2):

With bash while you can repeat a command until it fails
so if you want to drop all stashed items above and including X

```
while $(git stash drop stash@{X}); do :; done
```

when removing one item from stash the others step forward, so repeating will remove all from X to the end

Comment: Nice solution !

Comment: the final error message is strange

Comment: I had to omit $(...) in the loop condition when I ran it in bash.

Comment: @Caveman74   O_o well this syntax just means do what's in parenthesis and result is used as argument of while, so it loops until it fails and stops. Maybe a bash expert will explain this :)

Answer (score 1):

Had issues with the answers here, this got it working for me:

```
for ((i=3; i<=23; i++)); do
  git stash drop stash@{3}
done
```

Just update `3` with the first index you want to delete, and `23` with the last index.